# Delete Key on Apple KeyBoard Deleting only 1 char at a time

Tags: macos, keyboard

I used to delete characters continuously by pressing my delete key on apple keyboard but for some reason now I can not do it. I have to release and press again to delete the previous character.

For example:

If I have a line like "This is a text to delete". In the past, I will just place my cursor at the end of the sentence.. e.g after delete and keep pressing delete key until the entire sentence is removed. Now, I have press the delete key and release for every character.

I have set keyboard setting to default but still see the same issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Rj

Comment: Are other keys like the arrow keys repeated?

Answer (score 16):

This might be a setting in your keyboard system preferences panel.  Try adjusting your Key Repeat setting as shown:
[image: Keyboard system preferences screenshot]

Comment: thanks I've been wondering about this for a few past os's

Comment: After update to Sierra, even though my sliders above were set correctly, key repeating wouldn't work. For me, it was enough to just move them a little and then move back.

Comment: on mac-os ventura i have to adjust the Delay until Repeat to Short as well

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings - keyboard - key repeat, change to fast - delay until repeat, change to short. [image: this is how it should look for fastest results]

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the Delay Until Repeat to short will also reduce the wait before the cursor starts moving.

Alternative Method: Holding down the option key while hitting delete enables you to delete a word at each press (except for punctuation).

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. It allowed me to delete at least one word at a time. Before it would only delete a letter at a time. Delete key used to delete an entire sentence but something went wrong. Deleting one word at a time really helps.

Answer (score -1):

go to settings.  click on keyboard icon.  under on screen key board, look for filter keys and turn it off.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions